# Encrypt Form Data MD5

Tags: html, forms, encryption, md5, password-encryption

I have the following form:

```
       <form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="logincheck.php" autocomplete="off" >
       <table>
       <tr>
       <td><label for="username">Username</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="username"></input></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
       <td><input name="password" type="password"></input></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"</input></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
       </form>
```

And loginsuccess.php has the following checks (there is more PHP code but this is the relevant part):

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['password']); 

$encrypted_mypassword=md5($password);

$query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$encrypted_mypassword."'"; 
$result = $connect->query($query);
```

The user should be taken to another page (which works without the new:

```
$encrypted_mypassword=md5($password);
```

But instead they are sent to the error page and it isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: `MD5` is a Hash-algorithm not an Encryption-algorithm. Change tags accordingly. Also `MD5` is concidered broken and should no longer be used.

Comment: yes I am aware of both. But I wish to use MD5. So could you help?..

Comment: There isn't enough information to construct a meaningful answer. What exactly isn't working? How do you check the result? How is the user "taken to another page"?

Comment: Yes there is enough information. None of that is relevant. The only help I need is how to hash the password. When I use $password everything works and I am sent to the correct page, if I use $encrypted_mypassword then I am sent to the error page which means I have entered incorrect details

Comment: Now that is a better explanation. The solutions seems simple: You've stored the passwords in **plaintext** in the database. You should store the hash of the passwords instead.

Comment: I have just tried that and I am still being sent to the error page and cannot log in

Comment: Actually it seems to be working now thank you

Comment: Good. Made an answer of my comment.

Comment: PHP has bcrypt functionality, you should use that instead.

Comment: Why do you wish to use MD5 if you know it is broken? Unsalted MD5 is especially risky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you store the passwords in **plaintext** in the database. You need to store the *hash* of the passwords instead.

Bear in mind that MD5 is, these days, not an appropriate algorithm to use for password hashing, especially if it is also to be used unsalted. It is too fast, and can be brute-force searched relatively easily. Use `password_hash()` instead.